# Core data database and application reinstall

Tags: ios, core-data

Does the core data database in iOS delete all the existing rows when we reinstall the application using xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install app in Xcode:

1. Delete old app, and then install: *In this case, core data database will be deleted.*
2. Install while old app exists: *In this case, core data will do nothing.*

**In most cases**, the second one is what we should take care of. 
If you change your table in core data, **YOU SHOULD TELL CORE DATA TO DO MIGRATION**. This is what you need:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES, 
                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES};
NSError *error;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];

if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                               configuration:nil 
                                                         URL:storeUrl 
                                                     options:options 
                                                      error:&error]) {
    // Handle error
    NSLog(@"Problem with PersistentStoreCoordinator: %@",error);
}
```

*NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = YES;* does the trick. **I think you should always do like this.**